# Upload file to server, then attach to email and send in asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am having a application that uploads files according to the user input.. that upload an image to a folder on my web server. I now want the script to send an email with the image attached after it's uploaded

Any help is really appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you do this in the code and don't monitor the folder on your server for any changes! EG, after the upload is complete send the email using CDOSYS

I am going to assume you know the file name and file location and can store this path as a variable. I don't know what variable name you chose so I will use a variable called `uploadedFilePath`

```
<%
Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="mail.yourDomainName.com"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="myEmail@myDomainName.com"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="myPassword"

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

ObjSendMail.To = "someone@AntoherDomain.com"
ObjSendMail.Subject = "Upload complete"
ObjSendMail.From = "me@myDomainName.com"
ObjSendMail.AddAttachment = uploadedFilePath

ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "<p>Hi,<br /> A file has been uploaded!</p>"    
ObjSendMail.Send    
Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: yes, it would help if I included that code. Updated my post @Affan