# send form and attachment together to email in Classic ASP

Tags: email, asp-classic

I need to support an old ASP website, and this is the what I need to create:

I need to create a form like name, telephone number and email. User also able to upload PDF attachment if theyt wanted to . When user click submit, the form detail with the attachment will be send to a specified email straight away.

So far:

I am able to create a form and submit to email in ASP
I am able to upload files to server.

The issue is I cannot send form and attachment together in an email.

P/S: is this code in the link work for my case:

[Upload file to server, then attach to email and send in asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032851/upload-file-to-server-then-attach-to-email-and-send-in-asp)

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you determine what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code in the link you posted is exactly what you are looking for assuming you're using CDO to send your email. You would just have to also know the file location where the uploaded file has been stored so you can put that in the AddAttachment call.